# ffmpeg restreaming with an intermittent input

Tags: ffmpeg, multicast

I have a live unicast stream that I restream as multicast. This works fine:

```
ffmpeg -i <uri> -c:v copy -an -f rtp rtp://<multicast_ip>:<port>
```

However, on occasion the input stream may drop out briefly, or take a long time to join initially.

In these circumstances I would ideally like the multicast output stream to still exist, perhhaps using some kind of placeholder image, so that a viewing client does not have to re-request the stream whenever this happens.

I have been trying a few things out using concat and map, but I suspect this is not actually possible....does anyone know otherwise?